# ElectronJS build doesn't include needed folder

Tags: node.js, electron, node-modules, packaging, electron-builder

I'm working on a **ElectronJS** and **ExpressJS** project to build an application that runs an **API** in **background** and show a system tray with some features to **control and monitor** that API.

```
"electron": "^4.0.4",
"electron-builder": "^20.38.5",
```

I use `electron-builder` to **generate** an installer for macOS, and Windows (`.exe` with `nsis` and `.dmg`) **packages** containing my **express** API built app as it is.

That's mean, I build it separately and call it's entry point `build/index.js` in my electron's **main.js**, Despite, that hook and everything else is fine in **development** env. But when i run the build, it show me that error:

```
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584:15)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (/Users/username/WebstormProjects/my-api-monitor/release/mac/API monitor.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/common/reset-search-paths.js:43:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:510:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:640:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/username/WebstormProjects/my-api-monitor/release/mac/API monitor.app/Contents/Resources/app/api/build/index.js:19:16)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/username/WebstormProjects/my-api-monitor/release/mac/API monitor.app/Contents/Resources/app/api/build/index.js:208:3)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:693:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:704:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:602:32)
```

I guess the problem is that the `node_modules` of my API in `/build` folder **isn't packaged** in the app, and i can't achieve that with the normal way documented in `electron-builder` readme.

For more details, here is my files tree.

[image]

Also, my **electron-builder** config. :

```
"asar": false,
"files": [
  "main.js",
  "api/**/*",
  "resources/**/*"
],
"directories": {
  "buildResources": "resources",
  "output": "release"
}
```

Same issue with or without `asar`, i jsut keep it false to check if folders and files are included right.

Any idea will be helpful.